# CS50 Cash valid input exits program

Tags: c, while-loop, return-value, do-while, cs50

I am not sure why my change value is never evaluated in the second loop nor does my print statement run at the end with coins outputted. When valid input is entered the program should convert the floating number to an int and enter the next while loop. Then depending on the change value should check if the condition is true in each if statement until the while condition is false.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int coins = 0;
    float n;
    int change;
    do
    {
       n = get_float("How much do I owe you? \n");
    } while (n < 0); // continue prompt while true less than zero

    change = n * 100;

    while (change > 0)
    {
        if (change > 25) // change .25 cents
        {
             coins = coins + 1;
             change = change - 25;
        }
        else if (change > 5 && change <= 10)  // change 10 cents
        {
             coins = coins + 1;
             change = change - 10;
        }
        else if (change > 1 && change <= 5)  // change 5 cents
        {
             coins = coins + 1;
             change = change - 5;
        }
        else  // change 1 cents
        {
             coins = coins + 1;
             change = change - 1;
         }
        return coins;
      }
    printf("%d\n", coins);
}
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Even a quick [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should help you find the problem really quickly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example of input and expected and actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the `return coins;` line which is inside the `while` loop.

You should write something like:

```
while (change > 0) 
{
    /*update coins and change
      but do not use return.*/
}

printf("%d\n", coins);

/* as return will exit from your function, 
    you want it at the end*/
return coins;
```

Comment: Thank you that helped out! Now I just need to fix my logic. But I see now where I went wrong.